# Enable Flight mode with out disabling the wifi and bluetooth in android

Tags: android

I want to enable Flight mode but if i enable flight mode i cant able to use bluetooth , wifi. my purpose is to restrict only  the receiving call and sms related things.

I tried the following, but its not working;

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, "cell,bluetooth");
```

can any one help me in this

Answer (score 2):

You can change what radios that will be turned off when air-plane mode is activated. If you do this before activating air-plane mode, it is possible to only turn off the radio cell.

*NOTE: Changing AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS affects the behavior of the system button for toggling air-plane.*

Here's some sample code, tested on Android 2.2.

```
// Toggle airplane mode.
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Change so that only radio cell is turned off
// NOTE: This affects the behavior of the system button for
// toggling air-plane mode. You might want to reset it, in order to
// maintain the system behavior.
Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver, 
    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, "cell"); 

// Post an intent to reload.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS seems to have not effect in later android versions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as im aware flight mode will cover selection of setting to disable all wireless communication.

If you wish to only disable parts this will have to be done individually, not via flight mode.

try a method for each part of communication you wish to terminate.

Comment: On my phone (stock HTC Desire with 2.2), WiFi is still accessible while in flight mode, but Bluetooth isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I can't guarantee that it will work properly on all devices.

```
private ITelephony getTelephonyService() {
    try {
        TelephonyManager oTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Method mGetITelephony = oTelephonyManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony", new Class[] {});
        mGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);
        return (ITelephony) mGetITelephony.invoke(oTelephonyManager, new Object[] {});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        boolean retval = getTelephonyService().setRadio(false);
        Log.v("Radio", "SetRadio : " + retval);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Radio", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

You will also need the ITelephony.aidl file. Create a package `com.android.internal.telephony` under your project's src folder and create a file `ITelephony.aidl` in it with the following content:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.internal.telephony;

import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Interface used to interact with the phone.  Mostly this is used by the
 * TelephonyManager class.  A few places are still using this directly.
 * Please clean them up if possible and use TelephonyManager insteadl.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
interface ITelephony {
    /**
     * Check to see if the radio is on or not.
     * @return returns true if the radio is on.
     */
    boolean isRadioOn();

    /**
     * Toggles the radio on or off.
     */
    void toggleRadioOnOff();

    /**
     * Set the radio to on or off
     */
    boolean setRadio(boolean turnOn);
}
```

Comment: These radio commands require the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission, which is only granted to system apps.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 settings array you can change:

```
airplane_mode_radios=cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax
airplane_mode_toggleable_radios=bluetooth,wifi,nfc
```

For example, if you like to prevent Bluetooth from getting disabled on Airplane mode on,
you can remove bluetooth from `airplane_mode_radios`

And if you like to prevent Bluetooth from getting enable if it was not enabled before (yes, it may happen sometimes when you toggle airplane mode on and then off)
so you may remove bluetooth from `airplane_mode_toggleable_radios` (It will still get enabled if it was enabled before airplane mode on and then off)

Using ADB:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_radios 'cell,wifi,nfc,wimax'
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_toggleable_radios 'wifi,nfc'
```

Using Programmatically:

```
Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_radios", "cell,wifi,nfc,wimax");
Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_toggleable_radios", "wifi,nfc");
```

*Note: When finished, please reboot your device*