# how to disable only radio cell in airplanemode android

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable Flight mode with out disabling the wifi and bluetooth in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105750/enable-flight-mode-with-out-disabling-the-wifi-and-bluetooth-in-android)

Any one tel me how to disable cell radio in airplane mode.

i have tried the below code its not working.

settings.system.putstring(getcontentresolver(),settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS,Settings.System.RADIO_CELL);

Settings.System.putInt(getcontentresolver(),settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);

there is no change in the  Settings - > wireless networks (This check box is not enabled)

i can able to make a cal also when i tried the above code/. please help me in this

Comment: Isn't this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/7105750/871819?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a broadcast after the:
`Settings.System.putInt(getcontentresolver(),settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);`

call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: i have already tried this also. even though nothing is's not working. i need to cut radio power or anything???? pls help me

Comment: hi thanks to all.. now its working. i have send false in the intent wrongly.

Comment: now its disabling call,bluetooth,wifi and all redio signals. how can i cut only the cell radio.I have written as follows
settings.system.putstring(getcontentresolver(),settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS,Settings.System.RADIO_CELL);

Settings.System.putInt(getcontentresolver(),settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED); intent.putExtra("state", true); sendBroadcast(intent); Is this procedure is correct ???????????????

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Intent b = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
b.putExtra("state", true);
ctx.sendBroadcast(b);
```

After you change the settings.