# Turn on/off phone cellular network android

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

Hi I am developing an android app, where I am trying to turn on/off the phone cellular network. I tried looking for solutions, but did not succeed.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code.did you mean mobile data?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by cellular network ? Flight Mode, Mobile Data ? Explain

Comment: Not the mobile data. I need to turn off the phone coverage. The user should not be able to make any outgoing/incoming calls and sms.

Comment: so you must use Flight Mode to do that, see second part of my answer

Comment: Well,the flight mode also turns off the wifi.I need the wifi ON. So I need to only turn off the phone coverage.

Comment: Also the flight mode control is been reverted by google from 4.2 onwards. So it does not work on the phone above 4.2+

Comment: it won't work on 4.2.x= because it now requires a WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission that is only available to system apps

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105750/enable-flight-mode-with-out-disabling-the-wifi-and-bluetooth-in-android

Comment: Still the code involves airplane mode and the code doesnt work on devices above 4.2+ because of know issue. I there any alternative way to disable phone coverage which works on all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

if your mean is to turn on /off airplane mode you can use following link

[Toggle airplane mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android).

and be sure that add following line to manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

/// Edit

As far as im aware flight mode will cover selection of setting to disable all wireless communication.

If you wish to only disable parts this will have to be done individually, not via flight mode.

try a method for each part of communication you wish to terminate.

Comment: Not the mobile data. I need to turn off the phone coverage. The user should not be able to make any outgoing/incoming calls and sms.