# Airplane Mode with out lose Wifi and Bluetooth using ADB

Tags: android, mobile, adb, airplane-mode

I am trying to enable/disable Airplane mode via ADB commands.

I have found the following adb commands for enable or disable Airplane mode.

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

But, wifi and bluetooth connection will be lost.
How can I execute aadb for flight mode with out lose wifi and bluetooth

Comment: I don't know a way to directly reach that goal. But maybe activate bluetooth and wifi manually after turning on airplane mode?

Comment: I want to achieve this with out lose the wifi and Bluetooth connectivity

Answer (score 2):

Start ADB shell:

```
adb shell
```

Set parameter `airplane_mode_radios` to whatever you want airplane mode to switch off. Possible values include `cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax`. For your needs exclude bluethooth:

```
settings put global airplane_mode_radios cell,wifi,nfc,wimax
```

To remove this setting and return defaults to airplane mode run:

```
delete global airplane_mode_radios
```

There's also `airplane_mode_toggleable_radios` setting which controls radios to be enabled again after turning airplane mode off. See [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52873091/4535033).