# Turning off cell radio when no calls are received

Tags: java, android

I am trying to detect if any calls are presently being attended or the cell phone is ringing.If not, the cell radio should switch off.Since I am using telephony manager for the first time. I am not able to rectify the error.
The error is " cannot resolve 'setRadioPower(?)'.

My MainActivity.java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
                (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone Is Ringing",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Currently in A call",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                     tm.setRadioPower(disabled);
                }
            }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }

}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vk9621.radiocall">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

My imports are:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Can someone tell me how to rectify this error?

Comment: and your error? what is happening with this code

Comment: show me your imports in java?and check twice setRadioPower exist in android.telephony.TelephonyManager?

Comment: Apparently setRadioPower() exists in android.hardware.radio. So.. How will my code change accordingly? @AjayPandya

Comment: I have added my imports in my question. @AjayPandya

Comment: TelephonyManager. object doesn't have any setRadioPower(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559612/how-to-make-an-fm-radio-application-in-android

Comment: Check that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7107796/957954

Answer (score 0):

The reason you won't find it in the developer docs is that it is hidden.
However, you may always find hidden methods in the Android Source Code.

Code reference: [public boolean setRadioPower(boolean turnOn){}](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-8.1.0_r20:frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java;drc=fd51a3ba00ae4ed2ef8ee0aca84822b9955f7a60;l=5509)

If your phone is not rooted, or if you do not have system permission `android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`, you won't be able to access this API.

However, if you do have those permissions, you can easily achieve this using the following code:

```
    ITelephony iTelephony = ITelephony.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
    try {
        iTelephony.setRadioPower(true);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```